# Searching in a text

Tags: php, search

Is there a PHP library (or maybe a snippet) which would cover the following search functionality?

- "an exact phrase"
- all these words
- this OR that
- this but -not -these

I have an array, which arrives from MySQL database, and would like to filter the items based on a query, which has one or more rules I've specified above. For example, the query may look like this: `word1 "word2 word3" -word4`. This query would return all items containing `word1` and `word2 word3` (phrase) in any order, but not `word4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with plain MySQL.

The functions have everything you need.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Boolean :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Example for a perfect match you use the `LIKE` keyword and `%`.

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `body` LIKE "%confused about%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must write your own code to search an array according to your requirement.

Maybe [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) guides you.

Or send sql command to your database as you your needs. LIKE"%etc%" OR key="word1" OR key="word2" OR key="word3" AND key IS NOT "word4". It's just a simple sql.